# PHP move files directory

Tags: php, file

I am trying to move my jpg image file from one directory to another using the rename() function. However it keeps on giving the error saying No such file or directory. I have changed it to the copy() function with the following error failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

I am trying this as following:

```
rename('/_upload/1.image.jpg', '/_accepted/test/1.image.jpg');
```

The file is orginally already in my htdocs/_upload folder. This PHP file is already in my htdocs folder. All permissions are set to 777 but giving the same error.

Comment: try to give complete absolute path

Comment: Are your directories *actually* in the root directory (`/`)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting `/` in your path, use `./`:

```
rename('./_upload/1.image.jpg', './_accepted/test/1.image.jpg');
```

`/` means that you are giving path starting the server's root directory.

`./` starts with your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the arguments to [`rename`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) are file names. `/_upload/1.image.jpg` is an absolute file name. That means, it is relative to the root directory. It is not relative to your server root, document root or current dierctory.

Answer (score 0):

try this to give complete abosolute path

```
rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_upload/1.image.jpg', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_accepted/test/1.image.jpg');
```